# Consider a Rectangle with a certain length and breadth in a 2d space. Assume the rectangle's 4 coordinates are A(x1,y1) B(x2,y2) C(x3,y3) D(x4,y4)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Use JavaScript:

- Consider a Rectangle with a certain length and breadth in a 2d space.
- Assume the rectangle's 4 coordinates are A(x1,y1) B(x2,y2) C(x3,y3) D(x4,y4)
- Pick N number of 2 dimensional random points inside the rectangle. The random points must be inside the rectangle.
- If the rectangle is divided into 4 equal parts p1,p2,p3 and p4, Analyze the probability of points getting into each sections of the rectangle.

This was asked in my interview. Anybody know the answer?

Comment: How is this a question about programming, let alone Javascript?

Comment: Point 4 is rather odd, with 4 equal size sections and random distribution surely the probability is always 25%, no need to analyse anything? What exactly was the expected output here?